# Android how to get distinct phone numbers

Tags: android, contacts

I'm currently using the following to retrieve contacts from the phone:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] columnName = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
Cursor contactsCursor = cr.query(uri, columnName, null, null, "display_name ASC");
```

Does anyone knows how to retrieve distinct phone numbers from Android phone?

Comment: you are able to get the contacts right??

Comment: Yes, I can. Only thing is that I'm seeing instances of 2 contacts whom are essentially the same person and phone number, but with a different name.

Comment: cant you validate before displaying??

Comment: I probably can, but what I'm looking for is a way to select DISTINCT phone numbers using the ContentResolver.query coding, similar to what I've posted.